Notification Banner not showing on android
I am creating an android app that will show a notification on a specific event.
A minimal helper class (without the intents and pending intents is shown below)
public class NotificationHelper {

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id";
    private static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "My Channel";
    private static final String CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION = "My Channel Description";

    public static void showNotification(Context context, String title, String message) {
        // Create a notification manager
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Create a notification channel for devices running Android Oreo and higher
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // Define the importance level of the notification channel
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

            // Create the notification channel
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, importance);

            // Set the description for the notification channel
            channel.setDescription(CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);

            // Configure notification channel settings
            channel.enableLights(true); // Enable notification light
            channel.setLightColor(Color.RED); // Set notification light color
            channel.enableVibration(true); // Enable vibration
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC); // Show on lock screen


            // Create the notification channel
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX) // or PRIORITY_MAX
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC); // Show on lock screen

        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }
}

and to get the notification i use
NotificationHelper.showNotification(this, "Hello", "This is a notification message.");

The issue i am facing here, when the notification happens, if the phone is locked i can see it. also sound and vibration are happening. but if the phone is unlocked or i am in the app, the banner is not showing. only vibration/sound is happening and the icon in the status bar.
i followed many tutorials / SO questions still same issue.
what is missing for the banner to show?
